# android update firmware on AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, firmware

I've tried to find a guide or sample to update firmware on IoT AOSP, but without success. The google sample on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/master/updater_sample/ is not clear and not easy to follow since android.os.UpdateEngine package cannot be imported. is there another approach to tackle firmware updates on AOSP?